# jQuery FileUpload callback for complete process done

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using [Blueimp Jquery File Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) to upload files. I want to do stuff when the complete upload process is done. So if I for example drag and drop 4 files (at once) I want to invoke some code when all files are uploaded. How can I do that?

I've tried playing around with lots of callbacks like `done`, `stop`, `progressall` etc but nothing seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I need to be sure that the last `done` has been called before I run my code.

I've come closest with `stop` but that seems to be running before `done` sometimes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** - I understand in the comments that the callbacks where triggered the same amount of time than the number of files to upload. So the correct answers is to use the callback "**always**" and put a counter. The count will increment each time that a file has been uploaded.

```
// Variables to put before the .fileUpload and to be init in "add"
var nbElementsToUpload = 0;
var nbElementsUploaded = 0;


.bind('fileuploadalways', function (e, data) {
    nbElementsUploaded++;
    if(nbElementsToUpload === nbElementsUploaded){
         /* All elements uploaded */
    }
})
```

> You are talking about the "last" done. What do you mean by that? Are you invoking 4 times the upload or one time with 4 files?
>
> You have a list of callbacks functions for the plugin.
>   https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options
>
> If you want to capture **successful** upload requests, then use "done"
>   https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#done
>
> If you want to capture **all** completed operations once done (including errors and abort), then use the callback "always".
>   https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#always
>
> I'm myself using this plugin without issues with "done" and "fail". Example:
>
> ```
> }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) { // code here })
>   .on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) { // code here })
> ```
>
> You can add console.log to correctly see what happends and in which order.
>
> Regards,

Comment: One time with 4 files was what i meant. Yes, I've found that list as well. Thank you.

Comment: So is it working? :) If yes please accept the answers to close the question.

Comment: As I wrote in my question I've played around with most callbacks already. "stop" is the best so far, and if I add a delay it might just do the trick. I was wondering if there where a better way...

Comment: I always upload 1 file at the time. So I'm not sure to understand why **"always"** is not the answers to your issue. Do you mean that the call back will be triggered X number of times depending of your number of files?

Comment: That is correct. 4 Files triggers always (and done if no errors) 4 times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97294/discussion-between-maxime-039-and-daker).